# Why after flushing arp are records set to failed

Tags: ip

after I use command `ip n flush all` and list records with `ip n` all records show FAILED. I have same result with deleting it with `ip n del 192.168.1.10 dev ens192`. Is that normal behavior? And why is that? I have to bring interface down to clear arp table. (I didn't try `arp` command, but this should work too)

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after the flush, I also have all records FAILED. After a while, thoses who were REACHABLE before flush come REACHABLE again, and those who were STALE keep FAILED or come STALE again.